# add force to object that has 2 different rigid bodies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I have a question about Unity3d physics and it is important for me to know what could be the approaches to it, because this is always a problem for me. I am trying to make a clone of "push'em all" mobile game. I have a player object that has a rigidbody and it has several game objects on it. And one game object "movingpusher" has also its own rigidbody. Now, if my enemies get in trigger with player object, they push the player forward but, I just use "AddForce" to player object's rigidbody and the result is like at the attached photo.
[image of the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/352QU.png)

And this is the code part

```
private void Awake()
     {
         EnemyController.PushPlayer += GetDamage;
         PlayerRigid = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
     }
   
     private void GetDamage()
     {
         Debug.Log("TakingDamage");
         gettingDamage = true;
         PlayerRigid.AddForce(StablePusher.forward * 50);
         PlayerRigid.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(0, 0, 5);
     }
```

Now, I added AddForce for the MovingPusher's rigidbody also, but they are not moving at the same time, first player object moves forward then movingpusher moves. I will be appreciated if you could share your ideas :)

Comment: Don't nest (parent) multiple Rigidbodies! Always makes the Physics go wonky... Use [Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html) instead!

Comment: @derHugo Hi, I tried to use it and now I have another question:) When I add force to object, it breaks the joint and unfortunately there is no enabled/disabled option for this joint component. So it was [written](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/151900) on unity forums that make `rigidBody.connectedBody = null` when you want to kinda disable it.  But while playing, even if object's connected body is null, it is not affected by AddForce. Normally if joint was broken, AddForce would affect the object and object would move forward, but in this case, it's not moving. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately the `joint.connectedBody = null;` is completely wrong ^^ From [`Joint.connectedBody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint-connectedBody.html) `If not set then the joint connects the object to a fixed point in world space.` It means the rigidbody will be fixed not to another Rigidbody but rather the scene space itself. Instead you would use `Destroy` and `AddComponent` for the Joint component